# Can HTTP multipart and chunking coexist?

Tags: java, http, chunked-encoding, http-chunked, multipartentity

I'm using apache `HttpClient` to **post** several files to server. Here's the code:

```
    public static HttpResponse stringResponsePost(String urlString, String content, byte[] image,
        HttpContext localContext, HttpClient httpclient) throws Exception {

    URL url = new URL(URLDecoder.decode(urlString, "utf-8"));
    URI u = url.toURI();

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost();
    post.setURI(u);

    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    StringBody sb = new StringBody(content, HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE_JSON, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    ByteArrayBody ib = new ByteArrayBody(image, HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE_JPEG, "image");

    reqEntity.addPart("interview_data", sb);
    reqEntity.addPart("interview_image", ib);
    post.setEntity(reqEntity);

    HttpResponse response = null;
    response = httpclient.execute(post, localContext);

    return response;
}
```

The problem is, `MultipartEntity` class only has `isChunked()` method (which always returns false), there is no "setChunked(boolean)" option if I wish to enable chucked encoding for my multipart entity.

My question is:

1. Can HTTP multipart and chunking coexist according to protocol specification? If not, why  other entities like `InputStreamEntity` class have `setChunked(boolean)` where `MultipartEntity` doesn't?
2. Is there any way to post multiple files "at once" with chunking enabled, more preferably with apache libraries?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got a solution for my second question, the trick is to write `MultipartEntity` to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, create a `ByteArrayEntity` from `ByteArrayOutputStream` and enable chunking on that. Here's the the code:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bArrOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // reqEntity is the MultipartEntity instance
    reqEntity.writeTo(bArrOS);
    bArrOS.flush();
    ByteArrayEntity bArrEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(bArrOS.toByteArray());
    bArrOS.close();

    bArrEntity.setChunked(true);
    bArrEntity.setContentEncoding(reqEntity.getContentEncoding());
    bArrEntity.setContentType(reqEntity.getContentType());

    // Set ByteArrayEntity to HttpPost
    post.setEntity(bArrEntity);
```